# Unable to resolve error in index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> err: file:///F:/test/controller/addcontrollers Failed to load
>   resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>   file:///F:/test/controller/showcontrollers Failed to load resource:
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> angular.min.js:37Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…2F%2F%2FF%3A%2Fworksapce%2Fangular%2Ftest%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A40%3A435)

index.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#AddOrders"> Add Order </a></li>
            <li><a href="#ShowOrders"> Show Order </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script src="controller/addcontrollers"></script>
<script src="controller/showcontrollers"></script>
```

Comment: **1.** Check first `</script>`. **2.** Don't see `ng-app`. **3.** To include JS file, you should use its extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They need to be .js files.
You're trying to load them like in node :-)

```
<script src="controller/addcontrollers.js"></script>
<script src="controller/showcontrollers.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is my app.js filevar app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/addOrder', {
        templateUrl: 'views/add_order.html',
        controller: 'AddOrderController'
      }).
      when('/showOrders', {
        templateUrl: 'views/show_orders.html',
        controller: 'ShowOrderController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/addOrder'
      });
  }]);

Comment: @BalaDev did correcting the src paths like I show you above work?

Comment: @itamer thank u.ya its correct but i throws anthor error "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…2F%2F%2FF%3A%2Fworksapce%2Fangular%2Ftest%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A40%3A435)"

Comment: @BalaDev that means you're probably not injecting a dependency properly. Check to make sure all your dependencies are included.

Answer (score 1):

Remove these script tag from your html.

```
 <script src="controller/addcontrollers"></script>
 <script src="controller/showcontrollers"></script>
```

Instead you can use these controllers like :

```
  <div class="container" ng-controller="addcontrollers">
                OR      
  <div class="container" ng-controller="showcontrollers">
```

Comment: Use angular.js instead of using angular.min.js. Then you can see what the error actually happening by pressing F12.

Comment: ya i changed but it comes angular is not defined

Comment: have you used ng-app = "app "  in your index page ?

Comment: ya i kept <body ng-app="app">